# How to mark exception as logged (and log it only once)?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nlog

I'd like simplify my current logging solution and extend `NLog` in such a way that I can log an exception only once but without checking whether it's already logged in each and every catch like in my current solution:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if (!ex.IsLogged())
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        ex.MarkAsLogged();
    }
    throw;
}


static bool IsLogged(this Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Data.ContainsKey("Logged");
}

static void MarkAsLogged(this Exception ex)
{
    if (!ex.IsLogged())
    {
        ex.Data["Logged"] = true;
    }
}
```

Can I somehow extend `NLog` so that the `Error` method internally checks whether an exception is already marked as logged?

EDIT:

The shortest solution that I came up with is this one:

```
public static Exception IfNotLogged(this Exception ex, Action logAction)
{
    if (ex.IsMarkedAsLogged() == true)
    {
        return ex;
    }
    logAction();
    ex.MarkAsLogged();
    return ex;
}
```

usage:

```
ex.IfNotLogged(() => logger.Error(ex));
```

...but still it does not work in `C++/CLI` and it has to be typed :-) Repeating the same code everywhere is not a good habit as I was taught so I'd rather delagate this responsibility to `NLog`.

Comment: just log it at the level at which you are willing to handle it?

Comment: The reason I log it like this is because of the stack trace. I don't want to have other stuff there that is not related to the acutal exception. It makes the debugging unecessary more complicated.

Comment: What about joining these two extension methods to one? Something like (this ex, logger) => if (!ex.Data.ContainsKey("Logged")) { logger.Error(ex); ex.Data["Logged"] = true; }

Comment: I actually do it like this in some places but for example in C++/CLI it is not possible to use this convinient extension syntax so I thought, why should I repeat the same lines of code everywhere. It would be much better to just write the logger.Error(...) call an let NLog check whether it already logged this particular exception. There are also a lot of places where I do not have this check yet so I get sometimes multiple lines in my log about the same error.

Comment: Why not add extension methods to NLog's logger which check the flag and then delegate the actual logging to the logger instance?

Comment: This almost seems like an anti-pattern. I think the stacktrace is one of the most usefull things you could get so you would want as much of the stacktrace as possible, as late as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only catch it once. It doesn't matter how far up the call stack that is: the Stack Trace will be accurate. It's when you catch and rethrow and catch again that the Stack Trace gets changed.

Catch it once, log it, handle it as you can and then don't throw it again, continue.

Comment: Indeed the question seems to be relevant to exception handling architecture. If OP wants to log an exception only once, only call the logger at the topmost level or don't rethrow it. If each method logs and rethrow exceptions it feels like a code smell

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer... I gave it a second thought and I think I over engineered it a bit.